# Publishing using the Facebook Graph API not always works

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Facebook app with a login option.

I log in using the following URL

https://www.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXXX&state=XXXXXX&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.23&scope=public_profile%2Cpublish_actions%2Cpublish_pages%2Cuser_managed_groups%2Cuser_likes%2Cmanage_pages

I have put XXXXXX in the last impotent fields.

From some reason, in some of the groups I manage to post with no problems and in some I get (#200) The user has not authorized the application to perform this action.

I know this is pretty much a general question, but someone may have encounter this issue before?

Thanks

Comment: do you manage those groups? are you admin of those?

Comment: No. I manage to post using the graph API but it fails on some groups...

Comment: on which groups exactly? again, are you admin of those? are they public?

Comment: I'm not admin, they are public. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the failing groups are closed, posting was successful on the public ones. Is there a way to post on closed groups using Graph API? Thanks

Comment: then it´s not possible at all afaik. only admins should be allowed to do that, probably for spam reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only happens for closed groups: Afaik it´s not possible to publish to closed groups if you are not an admin of the group. You would only need `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions` though.